# Exploring an MySQL file using HSQLDB sqltool

Tags: mysql, hsqldb, sqltools

I have a MySQL file that I would like to explore using sqltool. I do not want to deploy a MySQL database because I only need to run a few queries on the data; I do not need persistence.

I understand that sqltool will allow me to create an in-memory database and run queries on it. This is perfect for my use-case, but **how do I make it accept the MySQL dialect of SQL?**

Additionally, is the process the same for other dialects such as Postgres SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy a MySQL database.

The HSQLDB SqlTool allows you to connect to a MySQL server using the MySQL JDBC driver, or to any other database server such as PostgreSQL using the relevant JDBC driver.

The SqlTool also allows you to create an in-memory database when used with HSQLDB, but this type of database is different from a MySQL database.